# Managing data to send for MQTTAsync_sendMessage

Tags: c, mqtt, paho

Trying to write simple `MQTT` application with `Paho` library. I'm planning to create simple fire and forget not blocking function :

```
void send(char* data)
{
..
}
```

For this purpose I'm planning to use  MQTTAsync client. But how to pass data to connect event. I suppose it is not good style to define `char * dataToSend` globally.

```
void onConnect(void* context, MQTTAsync_successData* response)
{
        MQTTAsync client = (MQTTAsync)context;
        MQTTAsync_responseOptions opts = MQTTAsync_responseOptions_initializer;
        MQTTAsync_message pubmsg = MQTTAsync_message_initializer;
        int rc;
        printf("Successful connection\n");
        opts.onSuccess = onSend;
        opts.context = client;
        pubmsg.payload = dataToSend;
        pubmsg.payloadlen = strlen(dataToSend);
        pubmsg.qos = QOS;
        pubmsg.retained = 0;
        deliveredtoken = 0;
        if ((rc = MQTTAsync_sendMessage(client, TOPIC, &pubmsg, &opts)) != MQTTASYNC_SUCCESS)
        {
                printf("Failed to start sendMessage, return code %d\n", rc);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
}
```

I afraid of the fact that when I pass pointer of data and return from send function content of data string will not be available since the fact that it is local variable of function that calls send one.

How to build some mechanism that allocates memory for data to send, copies to it `data` and deallocates  when send complete. User that call `send` are not planning to handle memory management, they will use somehing like `send("Hello wrorld") ;`  I suppose I need something like list of data_to_send for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add some more context to the question, but the short answer is you don't.

You connect the client once when you launch the application and reuse the same client object for the life of the application. So when you want to send a message you should be already connected, no need to use the `onConnect` callback.

What you might do is use the `onConnect` callback to set a flag so the `send` function knows that the client has finished connecting if it is going to be called very soon after the application starts, just to make sure the client has finished connecting first.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to pass it using a structure in the context.

Something like:

```
typedef MQTTContext {
    MQTTAsync client;
    char*  dataToSend;
};
```

This will allow to get buffer (and MQTTclient) from this context structure.

```
void onConnect(void* context, MQTTAsync_successData* response)
{
    MQTTContext* ctx = (MQTTContext*)context;
    // retreive client
    MQTTAsync client = ctx->client;

    ...
    // retreive message to publish
    pubmsg.payload = ctx->dataToSend;
    ...
}
```

In your send function you could store message in this context structure

```
void send(char* data)
{
    MQTTAsync client;
    // store in context structure client and message to publish
    MQTTContext* ctx = (MQTTContext*)malloc(sizeof(MQTTContext));
    ctx->client = client;
    ctx->dataToSend = strdup(data);

    MQTTAsync_connectOptions conn_opts = MQTTAsync_connectOptions_initializer;
    ...
    conn_opts.context = ctx;
    MQTTAsync_connect(client, &conn_opts);  
}
```

Comment: I afraid of the fact that when I pass pointer  of `data` and return from `send` function content of data string will not be available since the fact that it is local variable of function that calls `send` one.

Comment: So, my question is how to build some mechanism that allocates memory for data to send, copies to it `data` and deallocates  when send complete. User that call `send` are not planning to handle memory management, they will use somehing like `send("Hello wrorld") ;`  I suppose I need something like list of data_to_send for this purpose

Comment: calling malloc(or strdup that call malloc) and then free when you don't need it.